# Double google anaylatics on my template?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm not a coder though I've learned alot from this board. My friend set up a template for me to work from. there is 2 versions of google anaylatic script in there and i'm not sure which to use?

```
    <script>
        (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
        function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
        e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
        e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
        ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
    </script>
```

or....

```
    <script>  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||
               function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
               a=s.createElement(o),  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
               a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
               })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); 
               ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');  ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I would use the second one. Also, I believe you need to replace UA-XXXXX-X with you ga code? If he built a template, maybe he scaffolded with a tool that automatically added those. You can even get rid of the two. If you do, you can go to your own google analytics page and request the snippet, with the right UA-Xx... Copy from there, then paste it in your code replacing those two.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @quilesbaker ! Just out of curiousity, whats the difference between the 2, and yes I know to replace the number. One script is at the top of the page and second code is at the bottom. where would be the best place to put it? Does it even matter or will it slow my site down if its at the top? (since i think it will load that first?)

Comment: It is better if the tag is at the bottom, just before closing the `body` HTML tag. Like you said, it would slow down (a tiiiny bit) if its in the `head` tag.

Comment: Oh and the difference between the two, if they were both in the body tag, is just the letters used to name the variables. Possibly any of the two would work.

Comment: @quilesbaker ahhh okay thanks, i'll delete both and grab one from google whichever one they offer. should i have all my scripts at the bottom then? I have one for addthis. though i find that their buttons is always the last to load when i load my page. would putting their script at the bottom make this even slower? Sorry these are probably super noob questions haha

Comment: That is the best option- adding the script provided to you by google analytics. And yeah, I usually move all my scripts right before the body tag closes. I leave the head tag with css and other meta information only. Test it out and make sure everything works afterwards :)

Comment: @quilesbaker will do! thanks alot for the help. can't wait to finish this site. coding is hard for an artist lol. http://jamesngart.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the answer is: leave one with the correct GA Id. Remove any of them in the head tag, and leave the final snippet before closing the `body` tag.